# add new list into nested list

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I am writing an anagram finder program that could identify different words with same letters. 
For example:

```
input: ['cars', 'for', 'potatoes', 'racs', 'four', 'scar', 'creams', 'scream']
output: [ ["cars", "racs", "scar"], ["four"], ["for"], 
        ["potatoes"], ["creams","scream"] ]
```

This is the codes I have currently.

```
public List<List<string>> AnagramsFinder(List<string> words)
{
    List<List<string>> returnList = new List<List<string>>();


    for (int i = 0; i < words.Count; i++)
    {
        char[] inputCharArray = words[i].ToCharArray();

        Array.Sort(inputCharArray);

        string inputString = new string(inputCharArray);


        if (ReturnList.Contains(InputString))
        {
            ReturnList[InputString].Add(words[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            ReturnList.Add(InputString, new List<string>());
            ReturnList[InputString].Add(words[i]);
        }
    }

    return returnList;
}
```

The if-else statement is what I want to express but it is not valid in .NET WCF format. Can anyone help me to modify the if-else statement to achieve the same purpose? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: what's .NET WCF format? i presume you are having issues with the language syntax. From your text some are apparent so check the answers already provided. But anyway that won't solve your bigger issue : you're trying to use a programing language without previously learning said language. And as a future exercise if what you write doesn't compile learn to check the compiler errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED CODE**:

You can use following method to find Anagrame and just convert into list of list.

```
    public static List<List<string>> GetAnagramEquivalents(List<string> InputArray)
    {
        Dictionary<string, List<string>> DictionaryList = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        List<List<string>> ReturnList = new List<List<string>>();
        for (int x = 0; x < InputArray.Count; ++x)
        {
            char[] InputCharArray = InputArray[x].ToCharArray();
            Array.Sort(InputCharArray);
            string InputString = new string(InputCharArray);
            if (DictionaryList.ContainsKey(InputString))
            {
                DictionaryList[InputString].Add(InputArray[x]);
            }
            else
            {
                DictionaryList.Add(InputString, new List<string>());
                DictionaryList[InputString].Add(InputArray[x]);
            }
        }
        foreach (var item in DictionaryList)
        {
            ReturnList.Add(item.Value);
        }
        return ReturnList;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for posting. I saw this previously. But I got syntax error for rewriting ReturnList[InputString].Add(InputArray[x]); You have any idea on how to express ReturnList[InputString] in valid format?

Answer (score 1):

**C# language is case sensitive** so

`ReturnList` is not same with `returnList`, `InputString` is not same with `inputString`.

Old code:

```
if (ReturnList.Contains(InputString))
{
    ReturnList[InputString].Add(words[i]);
}
else
{
    ReturnList.Add(InputString, new List<string>());
    ReturnList[InputString].Add(words[i]);
}
```

good code:

```
if (returnList.Contains(inputString))
{
    returnList[inputString].Add(words[i]);
}
else
{
    returnList.Add(inputString, new List<string>());
    returnList[inputString].Add(words[i]);
}
```

**But**

```
 if (returnList.Contains(InputString))
```

`returnList` is a nested List of string, so the `Contains` parameter is invalid !

So iterate with foreach,

```
foreach( List<string> item in returnList )
{
  if( item.Contains(inputString) )
  ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I do know it is case sensitive. I was too rush to post the question and hence made those careless mistakes. But the most frustrating error is both returnList[inputString].Add(words[i]); and returnList.Add(inputString, new List<string>());
    returnList[inputString].Add(words[i]); got syntax error in VS 2010...Is there another way to express the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to compare a String to a List

Try:

```
foreach( List<string> eachList in returnList )
{
  if( eachList.Contains(InputString) )
  ...
}
```